# How to Bind current_youser.age to textbox

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
<input ng-model = "current_youser.age" >

y = {
    "name": "Harry Potter" ,
    "age": 18 ,
    "id": 200
}

$scope.current_youser = y ;
```

I want Harry Potter to appear on the textbox. How to do this?

Comment: you need to create a controller... look for this template: http://jsbin.com/solixi/edit?html,js,output

Comment: yes, i already have a controller. $scope.address , $scope.color is fine. But complicated things like current_youser.age dont bind. @joaozito-polo

Comment: your jsFiddle has no controller... Believe-me. lol... try to recreate your sample on a new jsbin and put here for we to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

**controller.js**

```
var y = [
    {
       "name": "Harry Potter" ,
        "age": 18 ,
        "id": 200
    }
];

angular.module('demoApp', [])
.controller('userCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.current_youser = y;
});
```

**html file**

```
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="userCtrl">
    <input ng-model = "current_youser[0].name" >
</div>
```

It works fine : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PPPWYM

Comment: If it works, can you mark my answer as solved ? Thanks.